Proof that the $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ (need check on intuition)
In this exercise, I am practising by trying to show that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$
I begin by stating I want to show that for any epsilon and for any $x$ in $\Bbb R$, there exists a rational number in the ball of radius epsilon centred around $x$.
Proof by contradiction:
Assuming by contradiction that there is an $x \in \Bbb R$ and an $\epsilon$ such that there is no rational number in the $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of $x$.
[from here, I think that implies there is a hole in $\Bbb R$, which will cause problems with the completeness property that every subset of R bounded from above must have a supremum in $\Bbb R$. But I am not sure how to proceed. Comments will be appreciated, or remote hints on how to steer my intuition from here]

I feel like a direct proof, rather than a proof by contradiction, is simplest here.  Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, can't you just choose a really large denominator $q$ (say, larger than $2/\varepsilon$), then show that $\lfloor{qx}\rfloor / q$ is always within $\varepsilon$ of $x$?

Hint: For a given natural number $n$, think about the set of rational numbers ${\frac m n \mid m \in \mathbb{Z}}$. What happens when $n$ is large?

Please format the mathematics in your question using MathJAX, see here for a how-to.

You can also see this question

Another way to say this is that you're looking for some rational $r$ so that $|x-r|<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. If $x$ is rational choose the midpoint between $x$ and $x+\epsilon$ and if $x$ is irrational you can truncate the decimal representation of $x$ at some appropriate spot to make a rational close to $x$.

@aschepler when holding m fixed? then the whole fraction will be very small

No, I mean: What does that whole set look like for a constant $n$? Then, increasing $n$ gives another set of the same sort. So what happens to the sets when that $n$ gets larger and larger? This isn't the only way to get started on thinking about it, though.

I advise against the approach being attempted by the original poster.  That is, it looks like the original poster is attempting to re-invent the wheel, which is generally a bad idea in math analysis.  In "Calculus" 2nd Ed. (Tom Apostol), Apostol leads up to the density assertions around $~\Bbb{Q}~$ and $~\Bbb{R \setminus Q},~$ by proving several preliminary assertions.  I suggest that the original poster look for a real analysis textbook that takes this type of incremental approach.

In addition, the OP's approach basically assumes the result to be proven. If there were an interval consisting entirely of irrational numbers, then there would be no "hole" in $\Bbb R$ and no contradiction. So the OP's approach (which admittedly is just recording their intuition) is just restating the problem, not making progress towards it.

Just consider the decimal expansion of the real number, and choose your rational number by taking as many digits as you want after the decimal point (by letting $N$ be large enough to satisfy $\epsilon > 10^{-N}$).

thanks all for your comments
